# Cordova: "Can't find variable: require"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic/AngularJS onto my Cordova application. After doing some tests, I got stuck at the following error from the debugger on my web browser console:

**Error: Can't find variable: require
signup@http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:56:28**

And this is the line corresponding to the error:
**var mongoose = require('mongoose');**

And this is where it is:

```
.controller('signupCtrl', function($scope)
        {
            /**
                     * init $scope.data
                     * @type {{}}
                     */

            function signup()
            {
                var mongo = require('mongoose');
                var crypto = require('crypto');
```

I tried to search everywhere about the problems related to require variable: But didn't yet find any solution that might solve my problem.

I need some help.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a module bundler (i.e. Webpack or Browserify)? Because if not, you can't use `require`. It's not something that's implemented in browsers. That said, even if you are, I doubt you'll be able to use `crypto`; that's one of Node's built in modules.

Comment: @JoeClay I tried re-testing with installing both Browserify and Webpack, but I'm still having the same problem even with using other external modules like with **require('mongoose')**.

Comment: It's not enough to just install Browserify/Webpack; they're command line tools that need [configuring and running](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto). That said, even with those tools you can't use Mongoose in an Angular app - that's a server-side library, Angular/Ionic are client-side.

Comment: @JoeClay I've read the docs, but I didn't understand how to configure the webpack.config.js for Ionic.

Comment: I don't use Ionic personally (wish I did, though - if anyone tries to make you use Kendo UI, run away), so I'm probably the wrong person to ask on that topic. If you google `ionic webpack` though, there's a lot of example projects that you might be able to look through for help.

Comment: @JoeClay Sorry for late reply. I used to follow a tutorial about Browserify, and then finished configuring. But after including the generated **bundle.js** script within index.html, I got the same results, even when using require with different modules, like in **require('minimongo')**.